# Big O notation result that involves limit of a function

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, algorithms

I have read a while a text (not a book) from a friend that says:

$\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{f(x)}{g(x)} = L \implies f = O(g)$

with L different of zero and infinity.

- Is it true?
- Can I use this result in case that I wanna prove that some function $f$ related to an algorithm is $O(g)$
- How can you prove this using a formal definition?

Answer (score 2):

> Yes, it is correct $f(n)\in O(g(n))\iff \exists c$
>    $\quad\lim\limits_{n\to \infty}\bigg|\frac{f(n)}{g(n)}\bigg|\leq c$

Also $f(n)\in O(g(n))\iff \exists n_0,c \quad \forall \quad n\geq n_0 |f(n)|\leq c\cdot |g(n)|$.

e.g suppose that the running time of algorithem $A$ is$f(n)=n \log n^5+ 6n$

we will show that $f(n)\in O(n \log n)$

$$\lim\limits_{n\to \infty}\frac{n \log n^5+6n}{n \log n}=\lim\limits_{n\to \infty}\frac{5 n \log n}{n \log n}+\lim\limits_{n\to \infty}\frac{6n}{n \log n}=5+\lim\limits_{n\to \infty}\frac{6}{ \log n}=5$$

If $f(n)\in O(g(n))$ it does not mean that alaweys $f(n)\leq g(n)$

Comment: So, I can use this result instead of the one in Wikipedia? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation You know, for make a prove of some function related to another function

Comment: @Nehorai  The limit condition is sufficient for $f\in O(g)$ but not necessary, since the limit need not exist. The OP is correct : the implication is one-way

Comment: This is awesome, thanks a lot.